# What is the difference of using "implementation platform(..." instead of dependencyManagement from io.spring.dependency-management gradle plugin

Tags: spring-boot, gradle

What is the difference of using dependencyManagement of the io.spring.dependency-management gradle plugin instead of using "implementation platform(..."?

```
dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:2022.0.3"
    }
}

dependencies {
  implementation platform("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:2022.0.3")
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's some discussion about the differences in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/spring-gradle-plugins/dependency-management-plugin/issues/211). To summarise, the two most notable differences in terms of features are that the dependency management plugin:

1. Allows properties in a bom to be overridden to easily control the version of multiple managed dependencies.
2. Applies exclusions declared in a dependency's pom as Maven intended.

The most notable difference in terms of performance is that Gradle's `platform` and `enforcedPlatform` support should be noticeably more efficient. Speaking as the main author of the dependency management plugin, unless you want to make use of the ability to override version properties, I would encourage you to use Gradle's `platform` and `enforcedPlatform` support.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and the link to the discussion. Because of a version conflict with httpclient5 i have to override the version property. I can't use enforcedPlatform but it would work with platform. An other drawback of "platform" is that you have to define the same platform dependency for annotationProcessor again. I will probably keep using dependency managment plugin because it's less configuration....

Comment: For exclude is use normally the following code. Is there a difference to the exclude in the dependency managment plugin?

`configurations {
    implementation {
        exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-logging' 
    }
}`

Comment: No, for excludes in your own build you should use Gradle's standard mechanisms.

Comment: I must correct myself. The statement that it would work with platform is not correct. The java-library project indeed build and a jar is created. But when the jar is used in another project gradle can't read the dependency "Problems reading data from Binary store in ....". When i exchange platform with the dependency management plugin than it works.